# Format Date in FormView EditItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net

This seems like it should be simple but I am at a total loss and the MSDN example on how to implement `FormView.EditItemTemplate` does not address formatting at all.  I have a `TextBox` I am able to bind to a field of type `Date` like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CheckDate") %>' />
```

However I am not using the time component and would like the existing value in edit mode to show up as the short date format.  Right now I get "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss".

Attempts to add formatting code to the `Bind` expression result in a compilation error, but I don't know any other way to set up a binding in the `FormView.EditItemTemplate`.  Help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Text='<%# Bind("CheckDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'
```

should work

But you could also do this in codebehind in a more readable way(IMO `ToShortDateString` is more readable than `Bind("CheckDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")`:

```
Private Sub FormView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView1.DataBound
        Select Case FormView1.CurrentMode
            Case FormViewMode.Edit
                Dim dr = DirectCast(FormView1.DataItem,DataRowView)
                Dim TextBox1 = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
                Dim CheckDate = DirectCast(dr("CheckDate"), Date)
                TextBox1.Text = CheckDate.ToShortDateString()
        End Select
   End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know `Bind()` accepts an optional format string.  `"{0:d}"` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the add'l example, could be useful if I need to do more complex manipulation of the initial values in the future.  Can I +1 you twice? ;)  IMO the inline example is the most readable (but the codebehind one is definitely the most "radable").

Answer (score 4):

you can use a **format string** as a **second parameter** in your `bind` property

```
<%# Bind("CheckDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>
```

a nice [set of patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) you can use to format the date

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{0:d}` in date format while binding or define the culture in Web.config to use *MM/dd/yyyy* format.