# Formating a date in the text of a label inside a form view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know if there's a easier way to format a label that is inside a form view, the code I use is this one, it's inside the event form view databound:

```
protected void FormView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormView2.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        Label DAT_Label1 = (Label)FormView2.FindControl("DAT_Label1");
        if (DAT_Label1 != null)
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(DAT_Label1.Text);
            DAT_Label1.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", date);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there no attribute in the label control that can help making this formating?

Comment: Can you get the value of the "data" variable to be formatted as you want outside the DataBound event? Then you would just bind it as you would any other value

Comment: Check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626819/format-date-in-formview-edititemtemplate

Comment: sorry, this variable data is actually the date, translated from portuguese to english but forget this one, already edited the question

Comment: Thanks raym0nd, it helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the standard [Short Date format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortDate) which is marginally less verbose than your code, but does have the advantage that it uses the users formatting style, so would display dd/mm/yyyy in the UK or mm/dd/yyyy if the locale is set to US

```
protected void FormView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (FormView2.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
{
    Label DAT_Label1 = (Label)FormView2.FindControl("DAT_Label1");
    if (DAT_Label1 != null)
    {
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(DAT_Label1.Text);
        DAT_Label1.Text = string.Format("{0:d}", date);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, way more easy to wirte just 0:d, and the question that raym0nd send also helped, since all my dates are bind, didn't knew you can send the format as argument when binding